# getting error "SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: express, prisma

I am trying to use Prisma.js in my express app. but I am getting error on module import. I am not sure where am I going wrong.

```
    'use strict';
var sql = require('../connection.js');
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
//const prisma = new PrismaClient()

class InvoiceService {
    constructor(){

    }

    getInvoices(body,query,user){
        
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            
            resolve(query);
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {InvoiceService};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the import to:

```
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
```

And it will work fine.

Comment: This should be the answer